# QtGui5 not loaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, winapi

I am developing an application in `C++`, `winApi` and `Qt`. What this application does is that it communicates through serial COM ports.
A user can open multiple pairs of ports and an opened port listens other port constantly.
To implement this functionality I use windows threads.There is a method named `startRead()` that  reads from other port constantly and changes the text area.

```
void SendAndReceive::startRead(){

    DWORD numRead = 0;
    std::string hex;

    while (1)
    {
        char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
        BOOL ret = ReadFile(portHandler, buffer, 500, &numRead, 0);
        if (!ret)
        {
            std::string errorMessage = "";
        }
        buffer[numRead] = '\0';
        std::string receivedData(buffer);
        QString QData(receivedData.c_str());
        if (ui->checkBox->isChecked())
        {
            std::string receivedData(buffer);
            hex= stringToHex(receivedData);
            QString QData1(hex.c_str());
            emit asHex(QData1);
        }

        QString QData2(receivedData.c_str()) ;
        emit finished(QData2);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

And there is another thread that writes data periodically to other port. For example , if you enter 2 seconds in a text line , the program writes data to other port at every 2 seconds and this method is `writePeriodic()`.

```
void SendAndReceive::writePeriodic(){
    DWORD numWritten;
    while (1 && checkWrite == true )
    {
        Concurrency::wait(timePeriod*1000);
        QString QData = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
        std::string data = QData.toStdString();
        WriteFile(portHandler, data.c_str(), strlen(data.c_str()), &numWritten, NULL);
    }
}
```

So when I run this program , program runs smoothly for 2 or 3 minutes and then it crashes and I get errors like "Program has stopped working" , "program closed unexpectedly".When I debug program , it says something like "Qt5Core not loaded" or "Qt5Gui not loaded".

Before I ask here , I did some search on the web . First I did not use `emit finished(QString)` signal , instead I directly manipulated GUI objects inside `startRead()` method.(I did something like `ui->text_edit->setText(some QString)`).But after some search I learn that I can not change GUI objects from another thread so I decided to use signal and slot mechanism and it has not solved my problem so far.I get same error again and again.Please tell me what I am doing wrong . If you need further explanation, I will happily give more details.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce** it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: In QtCreator application output says                         QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock'
(Make sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock'
(Make sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
 even though I did not use QTextCursor.

Comment: Qt has to honor the rules of the underlying windowing system. In Windows, you must not manipulate a window from any thread other than the owning thread. Manipulating widgets from another thread than the thread that created it is essentially the same. Don't do it.

Comment: I don't do it anyway . At first I did but then I have used signal and slot mechanism.You mean I can not even do "ui->textEdit->toPlainText();" ?

Comment: Why do you dynamically alloc buffer when it has fixed size? Wouldn't be easier and safer just to create `char buffer[500];` ? And it is not recommended to use `malloc` and `free` in C++ code. Mixing Qt with WinApi also usually is a bad idea - why do you want to use winapi if you have Qt classes? In Qt you have something like `QSerialPort`.

Comment: @Rames: Mixing Qt with the Windows API is safe, and hardly a bad idea.

Comment: @IInspectable right but what's the point? There's limited number of things you cannot do with Qt. Usually using Qt classes is easier and safer (in terms of being error prone). Communicating through COM port is one of them I believe.

Comment: I kind of had to use winapi because my superior asked me to do it in that way but are you suggesting if I use Qt classes instead of winapi the problem is solved ?

Comment: @Rames: The point is to avoid Qt where possible. The areas of Qt that aren't as mainstream as others are drowning in a sea of bugs. I stopped counting the bugs encountered trying to get something as trivial as `QLocalSocket`/`QLocalServer` off the ground. Mixing in the Windows API will in general improve the overall quality of a Qt application, not because the Windows API is inherently better, but because Qt sucks all around.

Comment: @IInspectable , I solved this problem by using Qt ports like you said  but I haven't figured out how to write to and read from a serial port at the same time.I searched web and I found if I set QSerialPort::AllDirections while setting baud rate , it would work but it hasn't so far. Could you please help me ?